# WebTestClient blocks in unit test when controller returns a EmitterProcessor instead of Flux

Tags: spring, unit-testing, spring-webflux, reactive

I am working on a project that uses the Spring WebFlux stack. We have a Controller where you can subscribe for updates on a specific object. This Controller returns an `EmitterProcessor` where clients can subscribe to. When something is published on the `EmitterProcessor`, subscribed clients get notified.

This works well in practice, but my unit test is failing. The unit test uses the [WebTestClient](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/reactive/server/WebTestClient.html), which blocks when an `exchange()` operation returns a `EmitterProcessor` (also tried with other `FluxProcessor` implementations such as `UnicastProcessor`). The error I get is the following:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Timeout on blocking read for 5000 MILLISECONDS

```
at reactor.core.publisher.BlockingSingleSubscriber.blockingGet(BlockingSingleSubscriber.java:117)
at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.block(Mono.java:1524)
at org.springframework.test.web.reactive.server.DefaultWebTestClient$DefaultRequestBodyUriSpec.exchange(DefaultWebTestClient.java:283)
```

I found this [thread](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/21781), which also reports that the `exchange()` method on the `WebTestClient` blocks, but as explained there it blocks only for retrieving the status and headers, so this should not be the problem. Also, in the case that a `Flux` is returned, this works fine, as demonstrated by the referenced [testcase](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/f30d19b72411485dc50057d7a21a05472c697747/spring-test/src/test/java/org/springframework/test/web/reactive/server/samples/ResponseEntityTests.java#L128-L144).

### Test case

I created a simple test case derived from the referenced test case and adapted it to return a `Flux` in one case and an `EmitterProcessor` in another case (which fails). As you might notice, the assertions for the `EmitterProcessor` should fail it, but it never gets there because of the blocking `exchange()` call.

Also notice that when I uncomment the line `processor.onNext("hello");`, this content is returned and the testcase succeeds.

```java
package test;

import static org.springframework.http.MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM;
import static org.springframework.http.MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.springframework.test.web.reactive.server.FluxExchangeResult;
import org.springframework.test.web.reactive.server.WebTestClient;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import reactor.core.publisher.EmitterProcessor;
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;
import reactor.test.StepVerifier;

public class ProcessorTest {

  private final WebTestClient client = WebTestClient.bindToController(new StringController()).configureClient().build();

  @Test
  public void entityStream() {

    FluxExchangeResult<String> result = client //
        .get().uri("/flux") //
        .accept(TEXT_EVENT_STREAM) //
        .exchange() //
        .expectStatus().isOk() //
        .expectHeader().contentTypeCompatibleWith(TEXT_EVENT_STREAM) //
        .returnResult(String.class);

    StepVerifier.create(result.getResponseBody()) //
        .expectNext("hello") //
        .thenCancel() //
        .verify();
  }

  @Test
  public void entityStreamProcessor() {

    FluxExchangeResult<String> result = client //
        .get().uri("/processor") //
        .accept(TEXT_EVENT_STREAM) //
        .exchange() //
        .expectStatus().isOk() //
        .expectHeader().contentTypeCompatibleWith(TEXT_EVENT_STREAM) //
        .returnResult(String.class);

    StepVerifier.create(result.getResponseBody()) //
        .expectNext("hello") //
        .thenCancel() //
        .verify();
  }

  @RestController
  static class StringController {

    @GetMapping(value = "/flux", produces = TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
    Flux<String> getFlux() {
      return Flux.just("hello");
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/processor", produces = TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
    Flux<String> getProcessor() {
      EmitterProcessor<String> processor = EmitterProcessor.create();
      // processor.onNext("hello");
      return processor;
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: Did you solve it ?

Comment: Unfortunately not. We ran into some other problems with Spring WebFlux and abandoned it. I have not followed developments in this area, but I would not be surprised if this has been fixed, or alternatives are in place. I know for instance that EmitterProcessor is deprecated now.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was the wrong value of `Content-Length` header in the response that caused `WebTestClient` blocked.